# Map a data collection to HTML elements

Tags: javascript

I retrieve an array of data from the local storage. And I wish to display that array as an HTML elements collection

```
  function getTodoItems() {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
            if (!dataArray[i].listItem.length) return;
            var value = dataArray[i].listItem;
            console.log(dataArray[i].listItem);



// What I tried, which showed the data, but I couldn't click on it.
        // var itemList = document.getElementById("my-todo-list");
        // var list = document.createElement("li");
        // itemList.appendChild(list);
        // list.innerHTML = dataArray[i].listItem;
        }
    }

getTodoItems();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/headbangz/2odzuc72/

Comment: I don't understand your question. Would not it be better  "how to get data from local storage ?"

Comment: my TODO list is made of "ul" and inside the "ul" there is "li"... i want the data to come as "li" in the "ul" when loaded

Comment: so you basically want to map an data array to a collection of LI elements ?

Comment: yes, exactly, but with functions intact as in i can remove the items again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the idea would be to iterate over your data collection. On each iteration, you would have to create the relevant HTML element and insert it within the container.

Note the sample below is an example. You might want to "batch" the insertion for performance reasons. In the same way there might be better alternatives to "clean" the container

```js
const dataArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']; //or coming from your local storage
const container = document.getElementById('container');

container.innerHTML = ''; //shortcut to remove every children elements

for (let item of dataArray){
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  li.textContent = item;
  container.appendChild(li)
}
```

```html
<ul id="container"></ul>
```

Comment: I could do that.. I needed teh functionality of being able to click for complete and remove the list item to be intact.. They ain't.. It is almost the same I did just a more pretty version of it than the lines i commented out